# Is that possible to preview my streaming data at bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Is that possible to preview my streaming data at bigquery?

I'm using bigquery to store my streaming data, but these data will go to streaming buffer which means I can't preview this data. Is there any way I can preview this data before conducting any query?

Answer (score 2):

If the issue is cost, you can use table decorators that will let you scan the "last x milliseconds", instead of doing a whole table/column scan.

For example, this query shows you the last 15 minutes of GDELT record, at a cost of 132 MB (instead of 2.91 TB without the `@-900000-` decorator):

```
SELECT *
FROM [gdelt-bq:gdeltv2.gkg@-900000-]
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: I see what you mean, but I was thinking that, if I want to just hand my BigQuery to my coworkers and they want to do some queries by themselves, it will be useful if they can visualize my streaming table structure before building their queries.  From your answer, I think I will build a small query for them to visualize my table structure.

Answer (score 2):

You can see streaming buffer stats via [Tables: get API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/get) - in [streamingBuffer](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#streamingBuffer) property

or in Web UI

[image]

Comment: As Felipe notes, you can kind of fake it with the range operators, as long as you haven't recently added data any other way. For an *empty* (or small) table,  you can also use `bq head` on the command line. The contents of the streaming buffer shows up in tabledata.list operations, it is just impractical for large tables.

Comment: that is a little surprise for me that rows in buffer are accessible for querying. somehow I thought they are not before they flushed from buffer. I will need to test this somehow for myself to feel comfortable with this idea. thank you for emphasizing thi spoint for me

Comment: The specific behavior is documented here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataavailability

Comment: I think I see it now. So streaming buffer is only delaying new data for copy and export. But for querying - data is available in real time. Thank you @AdamLydick - i was a little pessimistic on this one :o)

Comment: I noticed this feature and I guess it will take few minutes before you can see these info on you bigquery page, so it's a little bit annoy...